# How to get company's default currency in Apex for both single currency and multi currency orgs

Tags: apex, multi-currency, currency

**Background**

we are building an SF's custom app and cannot assume if [Multiple Currency Settings](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/company_wide_org_settings/org_settings_currency)is enabled or not (depends on the customer).

**What I want to do**

I want to get the organization's default currency (no matter what Multiple Currency Settings is).

**What I have tried**

A. `User.CurrencyIsoCode`

Problem: This code is not deployable in an org whose Multiple Currency Settings is NOT enabled.

```
User u = [select Id, CurrencyIsoCode from User][0];
System.debug(u.CurrencyIsoCode);
```

B. `CurrencyType`

Problem: same as above

```
CurrencyType c = [SELECT ISOCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsActive=TRUE and IsCorporate=TRUE];
System.debug(c.IsoCode);
```

C. `ConnectApi`

Problem: This code returns null in an org whose Multiple Currency Settings is enabled.

```
ConnectApi.OrganizationSettings settings=ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings();
System.debug(settings.features.defaultCurrencyIsoCode);
```

Thank you in advance.

---

Solution;

```
public class MyDebugClassMultiCurrency {
public MyDebugClassMultiCurrency(){
    Boolean multiCurrencyEnabled = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().containsKey('CurrencyType');
    if(multiCurrencyEnabled==true) {
        sObject sobj = Database.query('SELECT ISOCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsActive=TRUE and IsCorporate=TRUE');
        System.debug(sobj.get('ISOCode'));
    } else {
        ConnectApi.OrganizationSettings settings=ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings();
        System.debug(settings.features.defaultCurrencyIsoCode);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: To be disengaged from multi-currency, you must strictly use [Dynamic Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic.htm). This can be a bit of a problem, but it's the only real solution for now.

Comment: oh yea ! if multi-currency is on, i can use dynamic apex !

Comment: `sObject sobj = Database.query('SELECT ISOCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsActive=TRUE and IsCorporate=TRUE');`

Comment: thank you very much @sfdcfox !